# Unknown exception in delphi application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I write an application that works fine on my system, but since yesterday I realize that its not works on other computers.

This is the error that occurred in users system:

```
EReadError error 
Error reading
bmpAnimation.AnimationBitmap.PNG: Access violation at address 009BBCAC in
module 'Autorun.exe'. Read of address 000000000
```

I use madExcept and this is the bug report of it:

```
date/time         : 2013-04-13, 13:54:14, 962ms
computer name     : ----
user name         : ---
registered owner  : ----
operating system  : Windows 8 x64 build 9200
system language   : Persian
system up time    : 5 days 5 hours
program up time   : 291 milliseconds
processors        : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU Q 720 @ 1.60GHz
physical memory   : 2182/4025 MB (free/total)
free disk space   : (C:) 3/94 GB
display mode      : 1600x900, 32 bit
process id        : $1570
allocated memory  : 36/76 MB
executable        : Autorun.exe
exec. date/time   : 2013-04-13 13:50
version           : 1.0.0.0
compiled with     : Delphi XE3
madExcept version : 4.0.6
contact name      : 123
contact email     : m@gmail.com
callstack crc     : $8d28e808, $2a067771, $1d4b8f98
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EReadError
exception message : Error reading bmpAnimation.AnimationBitmap.PNG: Access violation at address 009BBCAC in module 'Autorun.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

main thread ($914):
004e0eef +0a7 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10436  +5 HandleException
004e1129 +1f5 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10493 +48 TReader.ReadProperty
004e09a5 +015 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10239  +1 TReader.ReadDataInner
004e0987 +067 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10232 +11 TReader.ReadData
004ec489 +001 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   15824  +0 TComponent.ReadState
004e07ff +11f Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10193 +23 TReader.ReadComponent
004e0a19 +089 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10247  +9 TReader.ReadDataInner
004e0958 +038 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10226  +5 TReader.ReadData
004ec489 +001 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   15824  +0 TComponent.ReadState
004e18ab +1d7 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10673 +37 TReader.ReadRootComponent
004dba0a +032 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    8267  +3 TStream.ReadComponent
004d1507 +057 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3820  +7 InternalReadComponentRes
004d2ce7 +05f Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3877  +4 InitComponent
004d2d75 +061 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3889  +6 InitInheritedComponent
00a6351f +0bb Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         2110  +9 TCommonCustomForm.Create
00a68e8e +016 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         3882  +1 TCustomForm.Create
00a5db47 +057 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms          939  +6 TApplication.CreateForm
00a5dd0b +05f Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms          984  +9 TApplication.RealCreateForms
009d3d7d +011 Autorun.exe  FMX.Platform.Win   461  +1 TPlatformWin.Run
00a62035 +0d1 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         1473 +12 TApplication.Run
00b71d6b +03b Autorun.exe  Autorun             19  +3 initialization
77518541 +00c KERNEL32.DLL                            BaseThreadInitThunk

main thread ($914), inner exception level 1:
>> EAccessViolation, Access violation at address 009BBCAC in module 'Autorun.exe'. Read of address 00000000
009bbcac +114 Autorun.exe  FMX.Canvas.D2D    1589 +33 TCanvasD2D.DoMapBitmap
00a317f9 +025 Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         8576  +2 TCanvas.MapBitmap
00a2c1f2 +016 Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         6735  +1 TBitmap.Map
009b81a3 +157 Autorun.exe  FMX.Canvas.D2D     386 +20 TBitmapCodecWIC.LoadFromStream
00408629 +01d Autorun.exe  System           16279  +2 @AfterConstruction
00a2a808 +094 Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         6163  +8 TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromStream
00a2c310 +0bc Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         6779 +17 TBitmap.LoadFromStream
00a2b64c +000 Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         6524  +0 TBitmap.ReadBitmap
004df412 +0fe Autorun.exe  System.Classes    9487 +16 TReader.DefineBinaryProperty
00a2b62f +02f Autorun.exe  FMX.Types         6519  +2 TBitmap.DefineProperties
004e10e3 +1af Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10487 +42 TReader.ReadProperty
004e09a5 +015 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10239  +1 TReader.ReadDataInner
004e0987 +067 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10232 +11 TReader.ReadData
004ec489 +001 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   15824  +0 TComponent.ReadState
004e07ff +11f Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10193 +23 TReader.ReadComponent
004e0a19 +089 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10247  +9 TReader.ReadDataInner
004e0958 +038 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10226  +5 TReader.ReadData
004ec489 +001 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   15824  +0 TComponent.ReadState
004e18ab +1d7 Autorun.exe  System.Classes   10673 +37 TReader.ReadRootComponent
004dba0a +032 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    8267  +3 TStream.ReadComponent
004d1507 +057 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3820  +7 InternalReadComponentRes
004d2ce7 +05f Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3877  +4 InitComponent
004d2d75 +061 Autorun.exe  System.Classes    3889  +6 InitInheritedComponent
00a6351f +0bb Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         2110  +9 TCommonCustomForm.Create
00a68e8e +016 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         3882  +1 TCustomForm.Create
00a5db47 +057 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms          939  +6 TApplication.CreateForm
00a5dd0b +05f Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms          984  +9 TApplication.RealCreateForms
009d3d7d +011 Autorun.exe  FMX.Platform.Win   461  +1 TPlatformWin.Run
00a62035 +0d1 Autorun.exe  FMX.Forms         1473 +12 TApplication.Run
00b71d6b +03b Autorun.exe  Autorun             19  +3 initialization
77518541 +00c KERNEL32.DLL                            BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $9e4:
7683c74c +00 KERNELBASE.dll  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
76da9773 +34 USER32.dll      MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
76da992b +1a USER32.dll      MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
77518541 +0c KERNEL32.DLL    BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $1804:
77518541 +c KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $1d2c: <priority:1>
76831123 +66 KERNELBASE.dll  WaitForSingleObjectEx
768310af +0d KERNELBASE.dll  WaitForSingleObject
77518541 +0c KERNEL32.DLL    BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $eec:
77518541 +c KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $1c18:
77518541 +c KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk

modules:
00400000 Autorun.exe          1.0.0.0             C:\Temp\Debug
67200000 nvwgf2um.dll         9.18.13.1106        C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
69740000 d2d1.dll             6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6b7e0000 DWRITE.DLL           6.2.9200.16433      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6be00000 d3d11.dll            6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6bfb0000 dxgi.dll             6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6c010000 d3d10_1core.dll      6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6c050000 d3d10_1.dll          6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6c080000 FaultRep.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
6cd60000 AcLayers.DLL         6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\AppPatch
6d020000 gdiplus.dll          6.2.9200.16518      C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9200.16518_none_ba1cf6b7e09f1918
6d3a0000 windowscodecs.dll    6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\system32
71a50000 SHCORE.DLL           6.2.9200.16433      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
71b00000 WINMMBASE.dll        6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
71d80000 dwmapi.dll           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
71da0000 MPR.dll              6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
71ec0000 winmm.dll            6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
71ff0000 apphelp.dll          6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\system32
724a0000 d3d9.dll             6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
73480000 sfc_os.DLL           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
73490000 sfc.dll              6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
73f70000 wsock32.dll          6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
741e0000 WINSTA.dll           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74220000 propsys.dll          7.0.9200.16420      C:\Windows\system32
74840000 uxtheme.dll          6.2.9200.16519      C:\Windows\system32
74910000 comctl32.dll         6.10.9200.16384     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16384_none_893961408605e985
74b10000 wtsapi32.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74cc0000 WINSPOOL.DRV         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74d20000 version.dll          6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74d30000 bcryptPrimitives.dll 6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74d90000 CRYPTBASE.dll        6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74da0000 SspiCli.dll          6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
74dc0000 SHELL32.dll          6.2.9200.16496      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
75e90000 OLEAUT32.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
75f20000 combase.dll          6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76060000 MSCTF.dll            6.2.9200.16496      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76150000 CFGMGR32.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
761a0000 GDI32.dll            6.2.9200.16433      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
762c0000 ole32.dll            6.2.9200.16451      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
765f0000 DEVOBJ.dll           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
767b0000 clbcatq.dll          2001.12.10130.16384 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76830000 KERNELBASE.dll       6.2.9200.16451      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
768e0000 SETUPAPI.dll         6.2.9200.16496      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76a90000 msvcrt.dll           7.0.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76cf0000 advapi32.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76da0000 USER32.dll           6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76ec0000 sechost.dll          6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76f00000 RPCRT4.dll           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
76fb0000 IMM32.DLL            6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\system32
77050000 NSI.dll              6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
774b0000 SHLWAPI.dll          6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
774f0000 KERNEL32.DLL         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
77620000 WS2_32.dll           6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
77670000 comdlg32.dll         6.2.9200.16384      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
77700000 ntdll.dll            6.2.9200.16420      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32


processes:
0000 Idle                   0 0    0
0004 System                 0 0    0
015c smss.exe               0 0    0
0224 csrss.exe              0 0    0
0284 wininit.exe            0 0    0
02ec services.exe           0 0    0
02f4 lsass.exe              0 0    0
0360 svchost.exe            0 0    0
0384 nvvsvc.exe             0 0    0
03a0 nvSCPAPISvr.exe        0 0    0
03cc svchost.exe            0 0    0
03fc svchost.exe            0 0    0
0174 svchost.exe            0 0    0
01e0 svchost.exe            0 0    0
0298 svchost.exe            0 0    0
0428 stacsv64.exe           0 0    0
0590 hpservice.exe          0 0    0
05dc svchost.exe            0 0    0
0678 spoolsv.exe            0 0    0
06b4 svchost.exe            0 0    0
06d0 svchost.exe            0 0    0
07b0 armsvc.exe             0 0    0
07c8 AESTSr64.exe           0 0    0
05cc BtwRSupportService.exe 0 0    0
0668 dasHost.exe            0 0    0
0788 nlssrv32.exe           0 0    0
0820 svchost.exe            0 0    0
0844 MsMpEng.exe            0 0    0
08c0 svchost.exe            0 0    0
04a8 svchost.exe            0 0    0
0de0 dllhost.exe            0 0    0
0c20 SearchIndexer.exe      0 0    0
1100 csrss.exe              3 0    0
0d64 winlogon.exe           3 0    0
1388 dwm.exe                3 0    0
14f8 taskhostex.exe         3 13   17  normal
17a4 taskhost.exe           3 9    11  normal
0b38 jusched.exe            3 9    2   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update
0448 WUDFHost.exe           0 0    0
0f70 WINWORD.EXE            3 549  96  normal
1a70 sppsvc.exe             0 0    0
14d4 SppExtComObj.Exe       0 0    0
0b44 explorer.exe           3 1761 820 normal
10fc chrome.exe             3 157  72  normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
0fd4 chrome.exe             3 13   4   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
15ac chrome.exe             3 12   2   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
092c chrome.exe             3 13   2   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
0930 chrome.exe             3 12   2   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
1838 chrome.exe             3 31   19  normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
1118 chrome.exe             3 161  2   below normal C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
1f5c chrome.exe             3 190  2   below normal C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
0ea0 IDMan.exe              3 96   70  normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager
1704 IEMonitor.exe          3 17   17  normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager
0e18 CamtasiaStudio.exe     3 1215 667 normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 7
1fec TSCHelp.exe            3 9    4   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 7
148c chrome.exe             3 80   2   below normal C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
0c5c audiodg.exe            0 0    0
17a8 SearchProtocolHost.exe 0 0    0
154c SearchFilterHost.exe   0 0    0   idle
14d0 dllhost.exe            3 0    0
1578 dllhost.exe            0 0    0
1570 Autorun.exe            3 61   47  normal       C:\Temp\Debug

hardware:
+ {1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}
  - Fax
  - Microsoft XPS Document Writer
  - Root Print Queue
+ {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
  - Generic USB Hub
  - Generic USB Hub
  - Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 3B34
  - Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 3B3C
  - Renesas USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 0096 (Microsoft)
.
  - USB Composite Device
  - USB Mass Storage Device
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub (xHCI)
+ {4d36e965-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - DTSOFT Virtual CdRom Device
  - Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM
  - Optiarc DVD RW AD-7700S ATA Device
  - TWXSJC 1UB8XEJOXYJ8 SCSI CdRom Device
+ {4d36e966-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - ACPI x64-based PC
+ {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Hitachi HTS725032A9A364 ATA Device
  - PHD 3.0 Silicon-Power USB Device
+ {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - NVIDIA Quadro FX 880M (driver 9.18.13.1106)
+ {4d36e96a-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - ATA Channel 0
  - ATA Channel 0
  - ATA Channel 1
  - ATA Channel 1
  - Ricoh Memory Stick Controller (driver 6.10.1.3)
  - Ricoh SD/MMC Host Controller (driver 6.10.1.3)
  - Ricoh xD-Picture Card Controller (driver 6.0.1.7)
  - Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
  - Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
+ {4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Standard PS/2 Keyboard
+ {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - IDT High Definition Audio CODEC (driver 6.10.6300.0)
  - NVIDIA High Definition Audio (driver 1.3.18.0)
  - NVIDIA High Definition Audio (driver 1.3.18.0)
  - NVIDIA High Definition Audio (driver 1.3.18.0)
  - NVIDIA High Definition Audio (driver 1.3.18.0)
+ {4d36e96d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Agere Systems HDA Modem
+ {4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Generic PnP Monitor
+ {4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - HID-compliant mouse
  - Synaptics PS/2 Port TouchPad (driver 15.0.24.0)
+ {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  - Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)
  - Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
  - Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  - Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
  - Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
  - Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  - WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
  - WAN Miniport (IP)
  - WAN Miniport (IPv6)
  - WAN Miniport (L2TP)
  - WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
  - WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
  - WAN Miniport (PPTP)
  - WAN Miniport (SSTP)
+ {4d36e977-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - Ricoh R/RL/5C476(II) or Compatible CardBus Controller
+ {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - ECP Printer Port (LPT1)
+ {4d36e97b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - ACEKJZHW IDE Controller
  - Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller
  - Microsoft VHD Loopback Controller
+ {4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  - ACPI Fixed Feature Button
  - ACPI Lid
  - ACPI Sleep Button
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - ACPI Thermal Zone
  - Composite Bus Enumerator
  - DAEMON Tools Virtual Bus (driver 5.0.1.282)
  - Direct Application Launch Button
  - Direct memory access controller
  - Extended IO Bus
  - Extended IO Bus
  - High Definition Audio Controller
  - High Definition Audio Controller
  - High precision event timer
  - HP Mobile Data Protection Sensor (driver 4.2.2.1)
  - Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 3B42
  - Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 3B44
  - Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 - 3B50
  - Intel(R) 82801 PCI Bridge - 2448
  - Intel(R) 82802 Firmware Hub Device
  - Intel(R) Management Engine Interface (driver 6.0.0.1179)
  - Intel(R) processor DMI - D132
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller - 2C98
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers - 2CA1
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers - 2CA0
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers - 2CA2
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers - 2CA3
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers - 2CA9
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers - 2CA8
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers - 2CAA
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers - 2CAB
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder - 2C99
  - Intel(R) processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers - 2C9C
  - Intel(R) processor Miscellaneous Registers - D158
  - Intel(R) processor PCI Express Root Port 1 - D138
  - Intel(R) processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers - D156
  - Intel(R) processor System Control and Status Registers - D157
  - Intel(R) processor System Management Registers - D155
  - Intel(R) QM57 Express Chipset LPC Interface Controller - 3B07
  - Intel(R) QPI Link - 2C90
  - Intel(R) QPI Physical 0 - 2C91
  - Intel(R) QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers - 2C52
  - Intel(R) QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder - 2C81
  - Intel(R) QuickPath Interconnect - D150
  - Intel(R) QuickPath Interconnect - D151
  - Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Embedded Controller
  - Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System
  - Microsoft Basic Display Driver
  - Microsoft Basic Render Driver
  - Microsoft System Management BIOS Driver
  - Microsoft Virtual Drive Enumerator
  - Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI
  - Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI
  - Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI
  - Motherboard resources
  - Motherboard resources
  - Motherboard resources
  - Numeric data processor
  - PCI bus
  - PCI Express Root Complex
  - Plug and Play Software Device Enumerator
  - Printer Port Logical Interface
  - Programmable interrupt controller
  - Remote Desktop Device Redirector Bus
  - System CMOS/real time clock
  - System timer
  - UMBus Enumerator
  - UMBus Root Bus Enumerator
  - Volume Manager
+ {50127dc3-0f36-415e-a6cc-4cb3be910b65}
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) CPU          Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
+ {50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}
  - RICOH SmartCard Reader (driver 1.7.0.1)
+ {533c5b84-ec70-11d2-9505-00c04f79deaf}
  - Generic volume shadow copy
+ {62f9c741-b25a-46ce-b54c-9bccce08b6f2}
  - Microsoft Device Association Root Enumerator
+ {6bdd1fc1-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
  - Ricoh 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
+ {6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
  - HP Webcam [2 MP Macro]
+ {72631e54-78a4-11d0-bcf7-00aa00b7b32a}
  - Microsoft AC Adapter
  - Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery
  - Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery
+ {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
  - USB Input Device
+ {a0a588a4-c46f-4b37-b7ea-c82fe89870c6}
  - SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
+ {c166523c-fe0c-4a94-a586-f1a80cfbbf3e}
  - Headphones (RTC) (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
  - Integrated Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
  - Line In (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
  - Microphone (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
  - Speakers / HP (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
+ {d94ee5d8-d189-4994-83d2-f68d7d41b0e6}
  - Trusted Platform Module 1.2
+ {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
  - Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth (driver 12.0.0.10)
  - Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
+ {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}
  - SP PHD U3

cpu registers:
eax = 00000000
ebx = 038fb190
ecx = ec001889
edx = 00000000
esi = 00000002
edi = 00000000
eip = 009bbcac
esp = 0018f930
ebp = 0018f9a0

stack dump:
0018f930  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0018f940  94 f9 18 00 d8 f9 18 00 - 98 92 40 00 a0 f9 18 00  ..........@.....
0018f950  01 00 00 00 9c 6f 9b 00 - 30 dd 91 03 00 00 00 00  .....o..0.......
0018f960  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 80 25 00 00 80 00 00 00  .........%......
0018f970  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 - 57 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ........W.......
0018f980  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00  ................
0018f990  00 00 00 00 32 12 a3 00 - 3a 12 a3 00 30 dd 91 00  ....2...:...0...
0018f9a0  b8 f9 18 00 fc 17 a3 00 - 00 fa 18 00 00 fa 18 00  ................
0018f9b0  01 00 00 00 30 dd 91 03 - 01 00 00 00 f7 c1 a2 00  ....0...........
0018f9c0  00 fa 18 00 30 fa 18 00 - 00 00 00 00 98 6a 9b 00  ....0........j..
0018f9d0  b0 b1 8f 03 a8 81 9b 00 - e4 f9 18 00 98 92 40 00  ..............@.
0018f9e0  30 fa 18 00 38 fa 18 00 - 98 92 40 00 30 fa 18 00  0...8.....@.0...
0018f9f0  98 6a 9b 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .j..............
0018fa00  38 fa 18 00 08 00 00 00 - 2c 86 40 00 80 00 00 00  8.......,.@.....
0018fa10  80 25 00 00 70 b1 8f 03 - 00 00 00 00 30 dd 91 03  .%..p.......0...
0018fa20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0018fa30  84 fa 18 00 0b a8 a2 00 - 44 fa 18 00 98 92 40 00  ........D.....@.
0018fa40  84 fa 18 00 50 fa 18 00 - 98 92 40 00 84 fa 18 00  ....P.....@.....
0018fa50  a4 fa 18 00 98 92 40 00 - 84 fa 18 00 30 dd 91 03  ......@.....0...
0018fa60  b0 b1 8f 03 d0 32 8f 03 - 10 15 90 03 00 00 00 00  .....2..........

disassembling:
[...]
009bbca3        push    0
009bbca5        push    esi
009bbca6        push    0
009bbca8        mov     eax, [ebx+$14]
009bbcab        push    eax
009bbcac      > mov     eax, [eax]
009bbcae        call    dword ptr [eax+$28]
009bbcb1        test    eax, $80000000
009bbcb6        setz    al
009bbcb9        test    al, al
009bbcbb        jz      loc_9bbcd3
[...]
```

but I don't know what is wrong in my code!

Help me please

Comment: The exception is raised in `TCanvasD2D.DoMapBitmap` at the line 1589 which reads `if Succeeded(H.MapBuffer.Map(0, Flags, 0, Mapped)) then`  Can you get some dissasembly too from madExcept

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've edit my post and complete the madExcept report

Answer (score 9):

My analysis of the madExcept trace is as follows:

1. The code is failing on line 1589 of `FMX.Canvas.D2D`.
2. That line does this: `H.MapBuffer.Map(0, Flags, 0, Mapped)`.
3. The disassembled code indicates that `MapBuffer` is `nil`.
4. The only place where `MapBuffer` is assigned to a non-nil value is earlier in the routine on line 1573 in the call to `CreateTexture2D`.
5. The code that calls `CreateTexture2D` does not check the return value of that call.
6. Since `MapBuffer` is `nil` then it would seem that the call to `CreateTexture2D` failed.

As to why it fails I could not say with the current information. However, it would seem to be a bug in the FMX code in the sense that the FMX code must check for errors and fails to do so. I suggest that you submit a QC report.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I find the problem. it occurred because an BitmapAnimationList was in my application!!! I removed it and problem is solved!

Comment: You still need to submit a QC report so that the bug can get fixed. And what are you going to do with this question?

Comment: I don't know how can I submit a QC report! I want to delete this question because I think it not useful for other people.

Comment: @sma6871: Please do not delete it. It can be very useful to other people. First, they may have the same exact problem, and your solution will help them. Second, David did a very nice job of showing how to debug this type of problem, and future readers may find that useful, too. David, +1.